# OpenGEO GPS questions

Tags: gps, leaflet, openlayers, geoserver

For the last two weeks I have been researching the GIS world for a project I have been tasked with. The end goal is to have thousands of GPS points with information bubbles when you click on the point. This was a pretty simple task and now I'm moving onto the next part of this and I need some help to point me in the correct direction for me to research. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an Alarm go off when I'm within a certain proximity to these points. I know the OpenGEO suite along with QGis has some GPS functions but what I'm looking for is something that can be used by someone either VIA web or a PC or mobile Application that will alarm on proximity. I have also been looking into Leaflet and OpenLayers in hopes I can do it through these map library's or in junction with them.

What are some ways I could do this? Please do not give me any code because I like to research things to learn. I just need some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Describe more: "I want to have an Alarm". Where is the system running? On an mobile device? or on an server? Where are the GPS points stored? locally on the mobile device. etc.

Comment: Its going to be running on a PC coded in Java. There are GPS points stored in a PostGIS database on the local machine. So for example when you get within 100 feet an alarm goes off. Also there will be a GPS connected to the computer.By the way this isn't off topic. I was not asking for a tutorial but more like a method to achieve the desired result for me to look into.

Comment: Ok so an local application that have access to all data localy: Import point in a binary format, create a spatial index, use distance(p1,p2) < p2.radius to check wheter point p1 is inside radius.of p2.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com) (if this then that). [Here, is a recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/276030-blink-lights-when-enter-exit-and-area-with-android-gps) that lights a philips hue light bulb when someone enters an area with android gps app. Best part, you don't have to code anything.

If your solution has to be more inhouse developed, you definitely have to read about the new [mysql gis functions](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/). IIRC, you have to use mysql 5.6 or newer.